Debug 'MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket' with localhost reference
I have a spring boot app with mongodb. It works fine with docker compose, but for the life of me I keep getting the below exception using kubernetes. Each time I edit the app, I'll rerun compose to update the containers and confirm it still works locally, then re-tag and re-push in docker to update any minute changes to the container so kubernetes references the most update container:
...: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

  com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.lambda$open$0(SocketStream.java:84) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.2.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:84) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:211) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:153) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.2.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:592) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:76) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:104) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:78) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.2.jar!/:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted

I've seen this and this and many other posts but nothing helped. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.
build.gradle
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.5'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'com.adarshr.test-logger' version '4.0.0'
}
group = 'com.app'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
java {
  sourceCompatibility = '21'
}
configurations {
  compileOnly {
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor
  }
}
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2'
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

properties
spring.application.name=islandzero
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongodb:27017/dev


main
package com.app.islandzero;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class IslandzeroApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IslandzeroApplication.class, args);
    }
}

controller
package com.app.islandzero.restservice;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.List;
import com.app.islandzero.entity.User;
import com.app.islandzero.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingRestController {

  private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
  private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
  public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
  }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        userRepository.deleteAll();
        userRepository.save(new User(0L, "Bill", "simmons"));
        userRepository.save(new User(1L, "Barry", "sims"));
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}

repo
package com.app.islandzero.repository;

import com.app.islandzero.entity.User;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {
}

Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/openjdk/jdk:21-ubuntu
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY build/libs/islandzero-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/app/islandzero-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/app/islandzero-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

compose file
services: 
  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./
    image: islandone-gradle:latest
    container_name: islandone-gradle
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: "always"
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongodb/{dbName}
    depends_on: 
      - mongodb
      
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongodb"

mongo yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongo-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 256Mi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    app: mongoserver
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongoserver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongoserver
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: jwinnd/m-0
          name: mongoserver
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-service
  labels:
    run: mongo-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mongoserver      

app yaml
greetingserver.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: greeting
  labels:
    app: greeting
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: greeting
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: greeting
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: jwinnd/islandone-gradle-kub
          name: greeting
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: greeting-service
  labels:
    run: greeting-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: greeting
  type: LoadBalancer


Your MongoDB Kubernetes service isn't called mongodb...

So with this one change, I still see the same error...kind: Service     metadata:
name: mongodb
